# Date range picker in Ember.view

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying implement Date range picker to ember view.

```
App.DaterangepickerView = Ember.View.extend({

    tagName: "input",
    attributeBindings: ["start", "end"],
    start: null,
    end: null,


    didInsertElement: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.$().daterangepicker(
               {
                 format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                 startDate: '2013-01-01',
                 endDate: '2013-12-31'
               },
               function(start, end) {
                        console.log("Date-range-picker:");
                        self.set('startdate',start.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
                        self.set('end',end.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
                        console.log("start: " + self.get('start'));
                        console.log("end: " + self.get('end'));
               }
        )
    },

});
```

template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="daterangepicker">


    {{view App.DaterangepickerView startBinding="start" endBinding="end"}}

    start date: {{start}}
    end date: {{end}}
</script>
```

controller:

```
App.DatatableController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    start: "2013-08-07",
    end: "2013-08-09",
});
```

startBinding and endBinding are probably wrong parameters of ember.view, but I don't know how to correctly write by contentBinding. Picker is shows and set a correct information to console, but I need set controller from there. Did you do something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `start` intead of `startdate`.

Update this code from:

```
self.set('start',start.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
```

To

```
self.set('startdate',start.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
```

so your `start` binding will work.

It's a good idea to pass the current `start` and `end` dates to `daterangepicker`, so when you show the picker it will have the selected value:

```
this.$().daterangepicker(
               {
                 startDate: this.get('start'),
                 endDate: this.get('end')
               }
```

The final result is the following:

```
App.DaterangepickerView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: "input",
    attributeBindings: ["start", "end"],
    start: null,
    end: null,
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    didInsertElement: function() {
        var self = this;
        var format = this.get('format');
        this.$().daterangepicker(
               {
                 format: format,
                 startDate: this.get('start'),
                 endDate: this.get('end')
               },
               function(start, end) {                        
                   self.set('start',start.format(format));
                   self.set('end',end.format(format));                        
               }
        )
    },

});
```

And this is a sample fiddle with this working http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/UTV3U/

I hope it helps

Comment: nice, thanks. 'start' instead of 'startdate': I forgot it from some testing. I had 'start', but it still didn't work. Maybe something with controller....

Comment: Hmmm, what is not working? In that fiddle the bindings are ok. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I have some more threads here, I will check them later. You are very active responder for emberjs questions, I'm glad for that :)